# Animation with canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I need to create animation with circle. When we see a block with a circle, then the animation starts to fill the boundary of the circle and stops in a certain position. Interesting how to do this animation on native js.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq7eb.jpg)

Comment: And your question is? Also, Show your efforts at implementing the animation.

Comment: Question is how to create this animation, i know how to draw this circle and text, but i dont' know how  to make it animated

Comment: @vlad draw again multiple times??

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to call `window.requestAnimationFrame`, which calls your render function. Within your render function you have to measure the elapsed time since your last animation frame (and calculate your new angle), redraw the animation and call requestAnimationFrame.

I quickly made a sample at [CodePen](https://codepen.io/stephtr/pen/awRKKE):

```
function draw(angle) { ... }

var duration = 3000; // duration of the animation in ms
var max_angle = 3 / 2 * Math.PI; // maximum animation angle

var angle = 0; // current animation angle
var lastRendered = performance.now();

function render(timestamp) {
  angle += (timestamp - lastRendered) * 2 * Math.PI / duration; // calculate new angle
  if (angle > max_angle) angle = max_angle;
  lastRendered = timestamp;
  draw(angle);
  if (angle < max_angle) requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

Comment: Orange quart of circle must make one spin and stop. And i don't how to make draw just one quart of circle. Maybe you know?

Comment: You will get better timing if you use the time that is the first argument of the callback given to `requestAnimationFrame`  eg `function render(time){` it is in milliseconds (1/1,000th) accurate to the microsecond (1/1,000,000th) and represents the time since the page loaded.

Comment: @Blindman67: Thanks, I updated it.

@Vlad: You are probably looking for the [ctx.arc function](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/arc), which has a `startAngle` and an `endAngle` attribute.
In your case the necessary call has to be something like `ctx.arc(100, 100, 90, angle - Math.PI / 2, angle)`. The startAngle is angle - π/2, the endAngle is startAngle + π/2 (one quarter). You could also add clipping at the animation's ends: [updated sample](https://codepen.io/stephtr/pen/awRKKE)